# Extracting route table from MVC app in T4 template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, t4

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might extract the route table from a MVC app in a T4 template ?

Ideally what Id like to do is create an instance of the 'MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication'  and get it to 'startup' so the routes are registered and I can just extract them from Routes.RouteTable.

Failing that, I thought about using reflection to find static classes with methods that follow the Register[xxxx]Route naming convention.  Would work in a lot of cases.

Any other suggestions I might have missed ?

Edit - seems to be some confusion over the question.  I know that T4 runs at design time.  I know that routes are registered at runtime.  This [guy](http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/12/20/asp-net-mvc-javascript-routing.aspx) did something similar to what im looking to do - extract roues at design time but he forces you to register routes in a particular way so he can use reflection to read them back out.  Wanted to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: What is the aim do you want to get?

Comment: I want to try and auto generate strongly typed helpers from the routes - which are basically wrapper methods around UrlHelper.RouteUrl.  I know I could use TVMC and ActionLinks as an alternative.

Comment: But... HttpApplication instance registers routes... Who do you expect would fill-in routes table that you'd like to read? You'd need some other way of configuring routes so your T4 would be able to read them. T4 is a design-time not a runtime execution.

Comment: Yes Robert I know that - its why I asked on StackOverflow.  I wondered if there was a way of explicitly creating the MvcApplication (in the T4 template) and forcing the initialisation code to run so the routes are registered (or if anyone had any other non-intrusive way of doing it).

Comment: While this is not what you asked for instead I would've tried, if possible, to define the routes in the TT file and generate the other artifacts from that. Another alternative is to use Roslyn to parse the syntax tree of the code that generates the route table and generate from that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use library Microsoft.Web.Mvc in MVC futures that has method

```
ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression<TController>(Expression<Action<TController>> action)
```

It give you what you want.

Update: it can work without Asp.Net MVC but you need to copy realization of Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper to your own class and remove restriction `where TController:Controller` from signature of GetRouteValuesFromExpression method:

```
public static class MyOwnExpressionHelper
{
    public static RouteValueDictionary GetRouteValuesFromExpression<TController>(Expression<Action<TController>> action) //where TController : Controller
    {
        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        MethodCallExpression call = action.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (call == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("MustBeMethodCall", "action");
        string name = typeof(TController).Name;
        if (!name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            throw new ArgumentException("TargetMustEndInController", "action");
        string str = name.Substring(0, name.Length - "Controller".Length);
        if (str.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("_CannotRouteToController", "action");
        string targetActionName = GetTargetActionName(call.Method);
        RouteValueDictionary rvd = new RouteValueDictionary();
        rvd.Add("Controller", (object)str);
        rvd.Add("Action", (object)targetActionName);
        ActionLinkAreaAttribute linkAreaAttribute = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<object>((IEnumerable<object>)typeof(TController).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ActionLinkAreaAttribute), true)) as ActionLinkAreaAttribute;
        if (linkAreaAttribute != null)
        {
            string area = linkAreaAttribute.Area;
            rvd.Add("Area", (object)area);
        }
        AddParameterValuesFromExpressionToDictionary(rvd, call);
        return rvd;
    }

    public static string GetInputName<TModel, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call)
            return GetInputName((MethodCallExpression)expression.Body).Substring(expression.Parameters[0].Name.Length + 1);
        else
            return expression.Body.ToString().Substring(expression.Parameters[0].Name.Length + 1);
    }

    private static string GetInputName(MethodCallExpression expression)
    {
        MethodCallExpression expression1 = expression.Object as MethodCallExpression;
        if (expression1 != null)
            return MyOwnExpressionHelper.GetInputName(expression1);
        else
            return expression.Object.ToString();
    }

    private static string GetTargetActionName(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        string name = methodInfo.Name;
        if (methodInfo.IsDefined(typeof(NonActionAttribute), true))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,"An Error", new object[1]
    {
      (object) name
    }));
        }
        else
        {
            ActionNameAttribute actionNameAttribute = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<ActionNameAttribute>(Enumerable.OfType<ActionNameAttribute>((IEnumerable)methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ActionNameAttribute), true)));
            if (actionNameAttribute != null)
                return actionNameAttribute.Name;
            if (methodInfo.DeclaringType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AsyncController)))
            {
                if (name.EndsWith("Async", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    return name.Substring(0, name.Length - "Async".Length);
                if (name.EndsWith("Completed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "CannotCallCompletedMethod", new object[1]
        {
          (object) name
        }));
            }
            return name;
        }
    }

    private static void AddParameterValuesFromExpressionToDictionary(RouteValueDictionary rvd, MethodCallExpression call)
    {
        ParameterInfo[] parameters = call.Method.GetParameters();
        if (parameters.Length <= 0)
            return;
        for (int index = 0; index < parameters.Length; ++index)
        {
            Expression expression = call.Arguments[index];
            ConstantExpression constantExpression = expression as ConstantExpression;
            object obj = constantExpression == null ? CachedExpressionCompiler.Evaluate(expression) : constantExpression.Value;
            rvd.Add(parameters[index].Name, obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So this will work from a T4 template ?  i.e. not part of a running MVC app.  WOuld try it myself but Im not in front of my PC.

Comment: Is your application an asp.net app?

Comment: But the question was whether this will run in T4? Which of course won't. That's what you should edit your answer.

Comment: My answer will work with T4. It is not needed registered routes cause it works with routedata, not with url.